# mysql: exclusive select like SQS?

Tags: mysql, sql, concurrency, amazon-sqs

Is there any way to simulate Amazon SQS message selection mechanism on mysql (exclusive selects)? I need this to use one mysql table for multiple ec2 instances that will process and delete rows from it.

`select ... for update` doesn't quite what I want because it locks a thread on select, and not returns not locked instances.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I came to this idea (don't implemented now):

1. alter target table, add columns lock_name, lock_time
2. on each iteration:

2.1. update target_table set lock_time = now(), lock_name = 'controller_instance_name' where lock_time < now() - visibilityTimeout

2.2. select * from target_table where lock_name = 'controller_instance_name' and lock_time > now() - visibilityTimeout

2.3 for each item in select

2.3.1 handle it

2.3.2 remove it from table: delete from target_table where id = ?

Each controller instance will be able to select row after it was locked more than on visibilityTimeout value.